# ngx-bootstrap modal: How to get a return value from a modal?

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, ngx-bootstrap, confirm-dialog

In my Angular 4 app, let's assume that I'm inside a service.

At some point, I want to ask the user for a confirmation, currently I'm doing it with just a `confirm(...)` request:

```js
const result = confirm('Are you sure?');
```

What if instead I would like to show an `ngx-bootstrap` **modal** with, let's say, two buttons "Yes" or "No" and obtain a similar result?

---

**EDIT**: in my case, I solved my issue by playing with Subjects. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46433195/angular-use-modal-dialog-in-candeactivate-guard-service-for-unsubmitted-changes/46451042) you can find my solution, in case it can be useful for someone else. However that solution does not solve **this** question which is about returning a value from a modal, so I leave it open.

Comment: Did you try something so far?

Comment: in my service I'm able to show the modal using `this.modalService.show(this.confirmModal)` but I don't know how to receive back the result of what the user clicked in the modal

Comment: @ShinDarth Just now only posted my answer.. i hope this will useful for you

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Try like this :

myexample it's working correctly. hope this will help you

**home.module.ts**

```js
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ModalModule.forRoot()
    ]
})
```

**home.component.html**

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openConfirmDialog()">Open Confirm box
</button>
```

**home.component.ts**

```js
import { BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/modal-options.class';

export class HomeComponent {
    public modalRef: BsModalRef;
    constructor(
        private homeService: HomeService,
        private modalService: BsModalService
    ) { }

    openConfirmDialog() {
        this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(HomeModalComponent);
        this.modalRef.content.onClose.subscribe(result => {
            console.log('results', result);
        })
    }
}
```

**home-modal.component.html**

```html
<div class="alert-box">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="bsModalRef.hide()">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        Are you sure want to delete this node?
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="onConfirm()">Yes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="onCancel()">No</button>        
    </div>
</div>
```

**home-modal.component.ts**

```js
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

export class HomeModalComponent {
    public onClose: Subject<boolean>;

    constructor(private _bsModalRef: BsModalRef) { }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.onClose = new Subject();
    }

    public onConfirm(): void {
        this.onClose.next(true);
        this._bsModalRef.hide();
    }

    public onCancel(): void {
        this.onClose.next(false);
        this._bsModalRef.hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but how would you use it inside a service? For example inside a `CanDeactivate` method of a Guard that it is supposed to return true or false, without waiting?

Comment: I need to replace this with a modal: ```canDeactivate() {
      return confirm(
        'are you sure?'
      );
    }
  }```

Comment: the `BsModalRef` path has changed from `ngx-bootstrap/modal` to `ngx-bootstrap/modal/bs-modal-ref.service`

Comment: Great! How can I customize `Are you sure want to delete this node?` , I means passing it as param to `openConfirmDialog`

Comment: How are you able to do `modalService.show(HomeModalComponent)` since `HomeModalComponent` is the export from another class and therefore in another file ?

Comment: @RezaRahmati, to customize message you can in home-modal.component.html change test to {{message}} and then to call show like this: `const config = { message: 'Are you sure want to delete this node?'}; this.modalService.show(HomeModalComponent, { initialState: config });`

Comment: What happen with Subject subscribed inside 'openConfirmDialog' if user clicks on backdrop?

Comment: We need to *unsubscribe* ones we go to another screen: something like: `ngOnDestroy() {
    this.bsModalRef.content.onClose.unsubscribe();
  }` **To avoid memory leaks**

Comment: Doesn't cover dismiss by ESC key or click on backdrop.

Answer (score 10):

I used the solution from @Chandru, however to *return* a `true` or `false`, instead of:

```
openConfirmDialog() {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(HomeModalComponent);
    this.modalRef.content.onClose.subscribe(result => {
        console.log('results', result);
    })
}
```

I simply used:

```
openConfirmDialog() {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(HomeModalComponent);
    return this.modalRef.content.onClose;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I understand that most of the answers above are completely valid, but that the main goal is be able to invoke the confirmation dialog in this way...

```
  async openModalConfirmation() {
    const result = await this.confirmationSvc.confirm('Confirm this...');
    if (result) {
      console.log('Yes!');
    } else {
      console.log('Oh no...');
    }
  }
```

Note that this is mostly syntactic sugar to simplify the use of a promise and the asynchronous stuff.

I think it's what the OP was looking for and probably can be reworked to support returning any other data type (apart from a boolean).

The rest of the code below (not including the template to keep this short), pretty straightforward..

**ModalConfirmationService**

```
import { ModalConfirmationComponent } from './component';

@Injectable()
export class ModalConfirmationService {

  constructor(private bsModalService: BsModalService) {}

  confirm(message: string): Promise<boolean> {
    const modal = this.bsModalService.show(ModalConfirmationComponent, { initialState: { message: message }});

    return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => modal.content.result.subscribe((result) => resolve(result) ));
  }
}
```

**ModalConfirmationComponent**

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/bs-modal-ref.service';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './component.html'
})
export class ModalConfirmationComponent {
  @Input() message: string;
  result: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

  constructor(public modalRef: BsModalRef) { }

  confirm(): void {
    this.result.next(true);
    this.modalRef.hide();
  }

  decline(): void {
    this.result.next(false);
    this.modalRef.hide();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

@ShinDarth You can add this function in your service and call this funcion whenever required.

In your Service, create this function

```
    openConfirmDialogBox() {
        this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(DemoModalComponent);
        this.modalRef.content.action.take(1)
            .subscribe((value) => {
                console.log(value) // here value passed on clicking ok will be printed in console. Here true will be printed if OK is clicked
                return value;
             }, (err) => {
                 return false;
        });
    }
```

In your demo-modal.component.ts, create an EventEmitter

```
 @Output() action = new EventEmitter();
 public onClickOK() {
    this.action.emit(true); //Can send your required data here instead of true
 }
 public onClickCANCEL() {
    this.action.emit(false); //Can send your required data here instead of true
 }
```

I hope this would help you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**home.component.ts**

```
import { BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

export class HomeComponent {
 public modalRef: BsModalRef;
 constructor(
    private modalService: BsModalService
 ) { }

 openConfirmDialog() {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(HomeModalComponent);

    this.modalRef.content.onClose = new Subject<boolean>();

    this.modalRef.content.onClose.subscribe(result => {
        console.log('results', result);
     })
 }
}
```

and

**home-modal.component.ts**

```
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
export class HomeModalComponent {

 constructor(private bsModalRef: BsModalRef) {

 }

 public ngOnInit(): void {
 }

 public onConfirm(): void {
    this.bsModalRef.content.onClose.next(true);
    this.bsModalRef.hide();
 }

 public onCancel(): void {
    this.bsModalRef.content.onClose.next(false);
    this.bsModalRef.hide();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a later version of Angular you might get an error due to the location of BsModalRef that had moved:

Use this location:

```
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/bs-modal-ref.service';
```

rather than:

```
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/modal-options.class';
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if that suits you, but I used a service with Subject.
In parent component it is enough to subscribe and unsubscribe, in modal component, when user clicks confirm button, then just emit value using next.

I'm sorry for not presenting a full example, but pseudocode below should present the idea.

Service:

```
export class SomeService{
    yourSubject: new Subject<string>();
}
```

Parent component:

```
...
ngOnInit(){
    this.bsModalRef = this.someService.yourSubject.subscribe ( val => ...);
}
ngOnDestroy(){
    this.bsModalRef.unsubscribe();
}
...
```

Modal component:

```
...
onSaveAction(){
    this.someService.yourSubject.next(val);
}
...
```

Ps. of course you need to provide service in proper place and inject it into components :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this!!!!
Create modal options with a yes function and a no function in the options.
Receive args as @Input...

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

@Component({
    selector: 'confirm-box',
    templateUrl: './confirm-box.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./confirm-box.component.css']
})
export class ConfirmBoxComponent implements OnInit {
    private _args: any;

    public get args(): any {
        return this._args;
    }

    @Input()
    public set args(value: any) {
        this._args = value;
    }

    constructor(private activeModal: BsModalRef) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }

    public no(): void {
        this.args.noFunction();
        this.activeModal.hide();
    }

    public yes(): void {
        this.args.yesFunction();
        this.activeModal.hide();
    }
}
```

And then the component or service that launches the dialog:

```
import { BsModalService, BsModalRef, ModalOptions } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { ConfirmBoxComponent } from '../../dialogs/confirm-box/confirm-box.component';

export class AreYouSure {    
    private activeModal: BsModalRef;

    constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) {
          //Wait five seconds before launching the confirmbox
          setTimeout(()=>{
             this.tryLaunchConfirm();
          }, 5000);
    }
    private tryLaunchConfirm(): void {
        const config: ModalOptions = {
            initialState: {
                args: {
                    title: "Confirm This",
                    message: "Are you really sure???",
                    yesFunction: () => { console.log("YES!!!! was clicked."); },
                    noFunction: () => { console.log("NO!!!! was clicked."); }
                }
            }
        }
        this.activeModal = this.modalService.show(ConfirmBoxComponent, config);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below option which is working for me.
callbackOnModelWindowClose is the return value.

```
@Output() callbackOnModelWindowClose: EventEmitter<null> = new EventEmitter();

const initialState = {
          isModelWindowView: true, bodyStyle: 'row', gridDataList: this.scheduleList
        };

this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(YourComponent,
          Object.assign({}, this.modalConfig, { class: 'modal-dialog-centered', initialState });

this.modalRef.content.callbackOnModelWindowClose.take(1).subscribe(() => {
            your code here..
          });
```