# Return value in function on buttonpress

Tags: angular, typescript

What I am trying to achieve is throwing a warning modal when the user tries to navigate from the create page without saving. Our application is using UI-Router. I am trying to use UI-Router's transition service to do this. I can stop the transition and it will continue or cancel it depending in the inner functions return value (true or false). My code so far:

```
ngOnInit() {
    //other code here
    const context = this;
    this.router.transitionService.onStart({}, function(transition) {
      context.openWarningDialog();
      // return boolean here
    });
  }
```

How can I return true or false in the function depending on which button the user presses on the modal?

Comment: Why aren't you using built-in routing ? The guard feature is literally made to handle this kind of behavior with `canDeactivate`

Comment: It is a big project and I can't change the routing just for this feature.

Comment: May I suggest to change the title?  It does not describe what you need to do

Comment: What should I change it to?

Comment: What kind of a modal are you using ? Is it ngx-bootstrap?

Comment: Yes, it is ngx-bootstrap.

Comment: You can find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46408428/ngx-bootstrap-modal-how-to-get-a-return-value-from-a-modal)