# ngx-bootstrap modal inside a ngx-bootstrap modal

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, ngx-bootstrap

I'm developing an Angular application. I have an **ngx-bootstrap** modal which in turn is launched from a "parent" bootstrap modal. that is, it's a modal nested in another modal.

The line of code to close the modals is: `this.bsModalRef.hide()`.

The thing is that it works perfectly when I click a button that triggers a function that executes that line of code, but, the big problem is when I execute the same line of code to close the **child** modal This one closes, but the **parent** modal loses the ability to **close**, even if hit the **Close** button which executes this line of code that closes the modal.

this is the button that closes the first ("parent") BsModalRef modal:

```
 <button class="btn btn-oval btn-sm ml-2"
        (click)=" closeModal()"
        type="button">
        Close
      </button>
```

this is the function in the .ts file that makes the "Close" button closes the first modal:

```
  closeModal() {
    this.bsModalRef.hide();
  }
```

Now, second modal also must have an option to close it and return to the previous modal, as in the first modal that also has a close button that also executes this to return to the main screen:

```
closeModal() {
    this.bsModalRef.hide();
  }
```

And effectively it closes the second modal, but when trying to close the first modal to return to the very main screen, this **Close** button stop working and there is no way to close it.

Why is this happening? Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: Please refer StackOverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46408428/ngx-bootstrap-modal-how-to-get-a-return-value-from-a-modal) as Example.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your using "bsModalRef" name in both child and parent component BsModalRef naming, change one to a different name.

Comment: if you can provide a working demo it would be more helpful to understand